# How are libgps debug levels set?

Tags: c++, gps, embedded-linux, scons, gpsd

Getting STATUS_NO_FIX after using libgps.so.25.0.0 built from gpsd-3.19.tar.gz for aarch64-linux-gnu embedded Linux target so trying to debug it. Building like this:

```
scons minimal=yes shared=True gpsd=False gpsdclients=False socket_export=yes clientdebug=yes
```

It looks like libgps_debug_trace is supposed to write to either stdout or stderr in the libgps source but I only see printfs from my own code which shows good gps sentences returned by gps_read in the message buffer. It looks like I also need to set a debug level but it is not clear how without changing the source, which I suspect is not necessary or desirable.

How are the debug levels set?
Are there other things I need to do to get the debug to print to the console besides clientdebug=yes?

Comment: *"How are the debug levels set?"* -- A call to the library routine **gpsmm_enable_debug()** according to [GPSD Client HOWTO](https://gpsd.gitlab.io/gpsd/client-howto.html)

Comment: Thanks a million! I should have read that entire howto before asking. If you move your comment to an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How are the debug levels set?

A call to the library routine **gpsmm_enable_debug()** according to the [GPSD Client HOWTO](https://gpsd.gitlab.io/gpsd/client-howto.html).  Refer to Table 1.